# Upgrading RAM Error

Tags: windows-7, memory

I am currently using a [M2N86-LA Narra6 motherboard](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01925534#N424), and I recently bought [CORSAIR Vengeance 8GB (2 x 4GB)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820145345).

I asked a lot of professionals and tech support if it would work and they said it would, but it would be pushed down to the limit the motherboard uses, which is okay, I don't mind. However, installing the RAM and going into the BIOS, I see that it says "No RAM Installed" but it boots up into Windows 7 64bit jsut fine. And when I check my computer specs through Windows, it reports back 8GB of RAM. Even the resource task manager reports it is all there.

So, it leads me to ask two things:

1. How do I get rid of the "no RAM installed" problem on the BIOS? Do I need an update and if so, where is the update and how would I do it? Bios currently says it is at 5.10 I do believe, but I will check again.
2. The RAM, despite being there and being used, is making my computer slower than the 3GB of RAM I had before. What could be causing this? It is an absolute fresh install of Windows with essential Windows processes working in the background except for Firefox, which I'm using now.

I have tried clearing CMOS and it did nothing. I tried one set of RAM, boot into the computer and still says nothing is installed but boots into computer just fine. I also tried seeing if I could edit the BIOS RAM settings, however, they seemed to be locked.

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAMs you bought are DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) RAMs, and according to your motherboards's website:

> Supported DIMM types:
>
> PC3-8500 (DDR3-1066)
>   PC3-10600 (DDR3-1333)

Which means you bought incompatible memory modules. The RAM you bought operate on a higher frequency (1600 MHz - with a bandwidth of 12800 MB/s) than your motherboard can support. I believe this is the reason of your system's behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. :)

That's what I thought when I was buying them but HP (I have an HP Compaq Presario) and Newegg tech support said that it will work only it will clock down to "1333MHz" instead of operating at the fullest speed available.

Should I stick with my old RAM then? They were stock ELPIDA  1333MHz ram, one was 1GB and the other was 2GB.

Comment: Then all I can say is using an up-to-date BIOS. I checked the website of the motherboard but couldn't find a link for a BIOS update. You should contact HP support about the update.

Comment: @LightningDragon well, let's wait for other answers. Maybe someone knows something about this and you can make use of your new RAMs. Otherwise, just stick with old RAMs, I'd say, since you say they provide better performance than new RAMs.

Comment: Okay, will do to both contacting support and waiting. I will try one more thing, one stick of 4GB of ram, and see if performance is better. If that doesn't work, I will temporarily revert back to my old RAM. :) and I tried to find the BIOS update too but can't seem to find it anywhere. Hopefully HP support can help me, which leads me to the forum.

Comment: Well, support couldn't help me but the HP forums provided some help. It might be because the RAM is so new the motherboard has trouble reading it through the BIOS or because the speed is being clock-downed. Either way it doesn't seem to be cause any problems, and the slowness seems to only happen when start up, so I guess a solution isn't needed at all. The "no RAM installed" probably isn't anything serious to worry about. :)

Comment: @LightningDragon good news, then:) Enjoy your new hardware.

Comment: @LightningDragon I'd appreciate if you accepted an answer, since your problem is sort of solved. Besides reputation is this communities motivation, it will bring some sort of closure to this question, i.e. this question will not be in the 'unanswered' category anymore. Also as a final note, welcome to the community. I hope you enjoy your time here.

Comment: @LightningDragon no problem. I hope you enjoy your time here.